# What is the source of this Wookiee mp4?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, episode-identification

https://pbs.twimg.com/tweet_video/CVGZQvjW4AAs1tf.mp4

I saw this on Twitter and I was curious where it  came from. It doesn't match any movie footage I know of. It may be from the Holiday Special.

Comment: From the what? I just see "from the ������� �������", must be a bug somewhere.

Comment: Wookies can smile?

Comment: It's Chewbacka's wife smiling in Star Wars Holiday Special: https://youtu.be/Z4CtXcjib4o?t=896

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Giphy](https://giphy.com/search/star-wars-holiday-special/3), which specializes in animated gifs, has this tagged as coming from the *Star Wars Holiday Special*.

Thanks to @user13267 for providing link and location, we can see the scene from that movie where the gif/mp4 was taken, a little before 15 minutes in.

[image: Screencap of the scene, showing timestamp]

Comment: That's a terrible "source". Anyone could put any hashtag on those gifs they want.

Comment: @CreationEdge updated.

Answer (score 8):

It is from the *[Star Wars Holiday Special](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Star_Wars_Holiday_Special)* and is a picture of [Mallatobuck](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mallatobuck) (Malla), Chewbacca's wife.

[A site devoted to the Holiday Special](http://www.starwarsholidayspecial.com/photos/wookiee_family.htm) has several alternate pictures of Malla and the other Wookiees who appear (his son Lumpy and his father-in-law Itchy).

Comment: The Holiday Special - it's not even 'so bad, it's good' - it's THAT bad

Comment: @NathanK.Campbell Or as XKCD described it, [So Bad It's Worse](http://xkcd.com/653/).